# Why my code is returning React Type Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I am passing props to child element I get the following error:

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FooterRightSideProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
>   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'FooterRightSideProps'.
>   Property 'onClickCreate' is missing in type '{}'.

My code is like below:

```
import React from "react";

import CSSModules from "react-css-modules";

import styles from "./Footer.module.sass";

import { Icon } from "@components/icon/Icon";
import { Link } from "@components/typography/link";
import { Button } from "@components/button/Button";

export interface FooterProps {
}

export const Footer: React.SFC<FooterProps> =
  CSSModules(styles)
  (
    (props: FooterProps) =>
    <div styleName="footer">
      <FooterLeftSide />
      <FooterRightSide { ...props } /> //an error occurs here
    </div>
  );

export const FooterLeftSide: React.SFC =
  CSSModules(styles)(
    () =>
    <div styleName="footer-left-side"></div>
  );

export interface FooterRightSideProps {
  onClickAbandon?: () => void;
  onClickCreate: () => void;
}

export const FooterRightSide: React.SFC<FooterRightSideProps> =
  CSSModules(styles)
    (
      (props: FooterRightSideProps) =>
        <div styleName="footer-right-side">
          <Link
            className="option-back"
            styleName="header-option"
            onClick={props.onClickAbandon}
          >
            <div styleName="icon-with-label">
              <Icon name="left" />
            </div>
            Abandon
          </Link>
          <Button
            onClick={props.onClickCreate}
            theme="primary-white"
          >
            Create Profile
          </Button>
        </div>
    );
```

Have any of you got an idea, how can I pass this `onClickCreate` prop to my child element nested in the parent?

Comment: where is `onClickCreate` defined?

Answer (score 0):

`props` that You are passing to `FooterRightSide` are of type `FooterProps`, but this component expects props that satisfy `FooterRightSideProps`.

Answer (score 0):

`export interface FooterProps extends FooterRightSideProps {}` and pass into Footer as a prop, either manually `<Footer onClickCreate={someCallbackReference} onClickAbandon={optionalSomeCallbackReference} />` or more probably from binding to a flux/redux store via an HOC, eg for redux...

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Dispatch, bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import * as someActions from './someActions'
import {YourApplicationStateShape} from './someStateInterfaces'

// your Footer definitions here...
// modify FooterProps in that to be...
export interface FooterProps extends FooterRightSideProps {}

export default connect(
  null, // no state props need mapping in this particular case
  (dispatch: Dispatch<YourApplicationStateShape>): FooterProps => 
    bindActionCreators({ 
      onClickCreate: () => someActions.createSomething() 
      onClickAbandon: () => someActions.abandonSomething() 
    }, dispatch) 
  )(Footer)
```